# Why don't I get actual error messages for AngularJS in Chrome? I only see "Uncaught object"

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

I know what the error is, it's that I didn't declare ngRoute, but while Firefox tells me that's the problem, Chrome only says "Uncaught object", even if I'm using the unminified versino of Angular.

What do I need to do to get Angular error messages to properly show in Chrome?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be helpful: [AngularJS debugging in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a lot as well. What I do is just simply run the same app on Firefox. FF gives a much more detailed stacktrace and more often than not, I get the root issue from FF.